# The size of my symbol gets too big when i zoom out in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google-maps. I am working on a project where i have to show a polyline with an arrow head. The size of the polyline is perfect but the arrow appears too big.
i am simply using this code.

```
var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    scale: 2
    };
var a = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1);
var b = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lon2);
var myTrip = [a, b];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: myTrip,
       icons: [{
         icon: lineSymbol,
         offset: '100%'
       }],
       strokeColor: "#8B0000",
       strokeOpacity: 0.8,
       strokeWeight: 6
 });
```

These links below are the ones i have seen but they are not close to what i need :)

The links i have seen are

- [Google Maps :: Changing icon based on zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047284/google-maps-changing-icon-based-on-zoom-level/13385598#13385598)
- ^I dont want to change the icon
- [Google maps V3: prevent marker scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667174/google-maps-v3-prevent-marker-scaling)
- ^I have to zoom in to see the line clearly
- https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=da
- ^Not exactly what i was looking for
- [Google Maps v3 fitBounds() Zoom too close for single marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334729/google-maps-v3-fitbounds-zoom-too-close-for-single-marker)
- ^Not what i need
- [Google Maps API Zoom in and out marke size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032739/google-maps-api-zoom-in-and-out-marke-size-change)
- ^May be possible duplicate but no one answered that either

Comment: The API doesn't change the size(scale) of symbols when the zoom changes, so how can the marker  get too big when the size didn't change?

Comment: i scale the symbol on zoom in and out events of map like scale = map.getZoom() * <my math if any>;. There are 0-21 zoom levels so you do the math how you want to scale your symbol accordingly.

Comment: Its like that the scale isnt applied.. It seems the same to me :/

Comment: @Abs should i save my symbols in a list then? as may be at one time i can have like 30 on the map..
but thanks for the comment... It gives more meaning than any post i have seen :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strategy described in your first link to do what you want.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    //this is where you will change your icon...     
  });
```

Inside that listener you can change the icon's `scale` property of your icon as well as any other properties you want to modify (maybe stroke weight, etc).